# Telethon: Can I generate a specific 'Padding' in send message?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telethon, mtproto

I use [Telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon) for creating a Telegram client.
I want to send a message with specific 'Padding' when I use `TelegramClient` Class and `send_message()` function. I edit `padding` variable at `encrypt_message_data()` function on `network/mtprotostate.py` but when I print `body` variable at `decrypt_message_data()` function, it has a different padding!
This is depends on protocol design (MTProto 2.0, part 1) or I am mistake in read/create 'Padding'?

Comment: Add significant portions of the code you use to clarify what you are doing.

Comment: You may be interested in reading through Telegram's documentation on MTProto https://core.telegram.org/mtproto.